# Ordering postgres indexes with GORM

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I would like to know how to set the default order for an index. Grails 2.3.3, postgres 9.

Goal is this index:

```
"crstate_idx" btree (cr_state, last_updated DESC)
```

This GORM code:

```
static mapping = {
    crState index: 'crState_Idx'
    lastUpdated index: 'crState_Idx' 
}
```

Gets me to:

```
"crstate_idx" btree (cr_state, last_updated)
```

How to add the DESC part?

Comment: Wouldn't be too surprised if it didn't support descending ordered indexes. Lots of schema generators don't seem to support anything beyond very basic indexing. Maybe it might have an `order: 'desc'` or `order: desc` you can tack on?

Comment: I think you can check the hibernate dialect for postgre to see if this option exists.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such thing as an descending index. B-tree indexes are just ordered from lowest to highest value. The DESC vs ASC is defined by if you start scanning it from the end or from the beginning. It's about the query you execute so i suggest you look up how to execute a query returning rows in descending order.

Comment: According to the postgres manual the create index allows order to be specified. The query is fine. It was for implementing a queue - the top is always grabbed, so logical to pre-sort. I can't remember testing a performance difference, whether as you say logically the index lookup operation is the same or whether a sort operation can be avoided. Index specification was the question, so this is an interesting point but doesn't answer the question. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: You are correct indeed - i never knew that. I guess DESC might be useful for monotonically decreasing serial columns.